# How to retain state (filter, selection, sorting, and pagination) of primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Im using `primefaces 5.0` and `mojarra 2.1.28`. There are two tab, one contain datatable with sorting, filtering, pagination and selection option and second tab contain the details of selected row. on row double click second tab open with details of selected row.

> Now the problem is, when i filter record and select or double click on row second tab open with details and when I come back to first tab my datatable reset its filter. same problem with pagination.

Is there any way to persist the state of datatable??

Additional info:

1. I'm not using lazy model, and don't want to use lazy model.
2. CDI bean in view scope.

Comment: `<p:dataTable>` using `LazyDataModel<T>` maintains its states correctly, when it is Ajaxically updated at least in the latest versions of PrimeFaces. Only the initial sort order is not maintained. Lazily loading data tables / data grids / data lists is very useful, especially when they are to be backed by a huge datasource having numerous rows which cannot otherwise be loaded eagerly. It is not clear why you do not want to use `LazyDataModel<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very tricky to find out your Problem if you don't show us the code...

In my imagination, your View looks like the following:

```
<h:form name="form" />
  <p:tabView id="tabs">
    <p:tab title="Table Tab">
      <p:datatable widgetVar="table">
        <p:column></p:column>
        <p:ajax event=”rowDblselect” update=”:form” />
      </p:datatable>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Detail Row">
      <p:outputPanel id="details">
        <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.rowDetail}" />
      </p:outputPanel>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

If this is the case, you are updating the datatable and the filters won't be reapplied. I suggest you one of the following solutions:

1. Just update the content of the second tab on the double click event:

   ```
   <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update=":form:tabs:details" />
   ```
2. Call the filter method on the datatable after updating:

   ```
   <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update=":form" oncomplete ="PF('table').filter();"/>
   ```

I think one of these solutions should fix your problem.

Comment: how can i switch from tab1 to tab2 when I double click on a row of datatable and datatable is on tab1???? for this I have to update complete tab view. isn't it??